# How do multiple relationships for a single node affect performance of a neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, relationship, graph-databases

I have a database which will store a number of users and the items belonging to those users. users and items will be stored as nodes. My initial approach was to have a user node with properties of username, email, and item with properties name and category, with their inbetween relatiohsip being:

```
(item)-[BELONGS_TO]->(user)
```

After reading an article in the [neo4j blog](https://neo4j.com/blog/dark-side-neo4j-worst-practices/), I moved the category property into a separate node, as it may belong to multiple items.

[image]

What I am concerned about is that now in a scenario of thousands of items, category nodes would have thousands of relationships. How would that affect the overall performance if I were to search for a single item and the categories it belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dense nodes are indeed an issue (and there's quite a few approaches to increase the performance / solve the issue). Having said that, the denseness here is on the side of the category (1 category having thousands of relationships with items). If your **entry point** into the graph is the item however ... getting all the categories it belongs to (just a few I imagine) should not cause any problems whatsoever.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to create `Category` nodes and the relationships to them by [indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) the `category` property of `Item` nodes. This would allow you to quickly find all the Items that belong to a single category.